# $_POST variable doesn't work in php Titanium

Tags: php, javascript, android, post, titanium-mobile

I'm trying to pass data between a JS file and a PHP file, but the variable `$_POST` in PHP doesn´t work and for that i can´t evolve in the app!

JS code:

```js
var params = String(input.value);
    var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
    xhr.open('GET','http://10.0.2.2/jobfinder/teste_demo_grafica/Resources/teste.php');
    xhr.send(params);
    xhr.onload = function(){

    var response = this.responseText;
    alert(response);
    if (response != null)
    {
        alert("voltou ao js e funca");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("-.-");
    }
    };

    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    xhr.onerror = function(e){alert('Transmission error: ' + e.error);};

});
```

and now the php code:

```php
<?php

// Connect to the database(host, username, password)
$con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','');

if (!$con)
{
    return ("Failed to make connection.");
    exit;
}

// Select the database. Enter the name of your database (not the same as the table name)
$db = mysql_select_db('jobfinder');
if (!$db)
{
    echo "Failed to select db.";
    exit;
}
$pesquisa= $_POST[params];
echo "pesquisa";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM oferta WHERE titulo like '%$pesquisa%'";  
$query = mysql_query($sql); 

if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0)
{

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    $response = array(
        'titulo' => $row['titulo'],
        'oferta' => $row['descricao_oferta']
    );
    json_encode($response);
    echo $response['titulo'];

}
else
{

    // Else the username and/or password was invalid! Create an array, json_encode it and echo it out
    $response =  array(
        'message' => 'Não existem ofertas para esta pesquisa'
    );
    json_encode($response);


}
echo "php mode off";
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a guess, your JavaScript is sending data via GET:

```
xhr.open('GET','http://10.0.2.2/jobfinder/teste_demo_grafica/Resources/teste.php');
```

but your PHP is looking for POST. Change the POST to GET and it may work. Or vice versa

Comment: this is the error: <b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: params in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\jobfinder\teste_demo_grafica\Resources\teste.php</b> on line <b>19</b><br />

Comment: @Vera: Make a `print_r($_GET)` (or `print_r($_POST)`, depending on what you use now) to see how PHP receives the data and then think about how to access it properly. You might have to adjust the data you send to make it accessible with PHP. (You get the error because you are using `$_POST[params]` instead of `$_POST['params']`, but I don't think you have a parameter with that name anyway).

Comment: i saw a tutorial that send the parameter like this:  xhr.send(params);

Comment: so my paremeter is 'params. but i will try like you said.

Comment: @Vera: No, PHP won't know about the therm "params", unless the **value** of `params` is something like `params=foo`. In `xhr.send(params)`, `params` is just the name of the variable in JavaScript. This information is not sent to PHP. Only the **value** is sent.

Comment: @FelixKling, so how can i pass the parameter ? i can´t figure it out... so how can the php receive the values pass in xhr.send(params)in php?

Comment: @Vera: Try `xhr.send('params=' + encodeURIComponent(input.value));` this would send `params=someValue` to the server (and encode it properly). Maybe you want to have a look at this [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/AJAX/Getting_Started).

Comment: @Vera: Because you run into problems if the value contains any character that is a special symbol in a URL or URI encoded data, such as `&` or even spaces sometimes, etc.... always encode the data (if you don't know what the value could be (which I don't ;))).

Comment: Have you tried returning a dump? like `var_dump($_POST);` or GET, eitherway. That way you can see the structure of the parameters as they are sent to PHP

Answer (score 1):

I have the solution now!
If we see this part of code:

```
var params = String(input.value);
 ** var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
    xhr.open('GET','http://10.0.2.2/jobfinder/teste_demo_grafica/Resources/teste.php');
    xhr.send(params);
    xhr.onload = function(){**

    var response = this.responseText;
    alert(response);
    if (response != null)
    {
        alert("voltou ao js e funca");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("-.-");
    }
    };

    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    xhr.onerror = function(e){alert('Transmission error: ' + e.error);};

});
```

the codw between ** is the problem...
so i do like this:

```
var url = "http://10.0.2.2/jobfinder/tessssssste/Resources/teste.php";//bug do titanium resolvido 
    var params = "?params=" + input.value;
    var encodedURI = encodeURI(url + params);

    var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
    xhr.open("GET", encodedURI);
    xhr.send();

    xhr.onload = function(){
```

and now it works
TY EVERYBODY!!!!