# Passing parametres between Javascript and php in Titanium

Tags: php, javascript, android, parameter-passing, titanium-mobile

I need help for one litle issue.
how can i pass values between javascript and php in titanium, I ask this because i try a lot of diferent version and none work.
Plz i need help fast.

Comment: Post something you've tried so we can help show you what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Titanium.Network.HTTPClient](http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient-object) for connecting to your php page in this way:

```
var downloadDataReq = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
downloadDataReq.onload = function() {
    var response = this.responseText;
    //some code
}
downloadDataReq.onerror = function(event) {
    //some code
};
var urlToDownloadData = "http://10.0.2.2/jobfinder/teste_demo_grafica/Resources/teste.php?param1=value1&param2=value2";
downloadDataReq.open("GET",urlToDownloadData);
downloadDataReq.send();
```

code for teste.php should be like this:

```
<?php
    $param1 = $_GET['param1'];
    $param2 = $_GET['param2'];
    //some code
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you take a look at the Appcelerator API? There are some nice examples for `HTTPClient`:

http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient-object.html

Comment: Hi! yes i took a look! I post this question because i allready put this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10171202/post-variable-doesent-work-in-php-titanium, but i'm very stuck and i'm disesperate!